# Elm can't find the elm whitespace error

Tags: compiler-errors, whitespace, elm

I keep getting a whitespace compiler error and I can't spot the error.
Here is the error

> I need whitespace, but got stuck on what looks like a new declaration.
>   You are either missing some stuff in the declaration above or just
>   need to add some spaces here:
>
> 41| view : Model -> Html -> Msg
>       ^ I am looking for one of the following things:
>
> ```
> whitespace
> ```

Here is the code

```
view : Model -> Html -> Msg
view model =
    div [] [
        h2 [] [text ("Counter: " ++ (toString model))]
        , button [type_ "button", onClick Add ] [text "add"]
        , button [type_ "button", onClick Sub ] [text "subtract"]
        , button [type_ "button", onClick Reset ] [text "reset"]
    ]
```

I have to be missing something very simple, but I can't spot it.

Comment: Can you include the code above the `view` function as well? The error is probably that the statement above this one is incomplete and so the compiler chokes when it gets to the `view` declaration, but the `view` function itself is fine (aside from the `Html Msg` type error).

Answer (score 1):

you need a few spaces after a function call. Like

```
x =
0
```

won't compile, but

```
x =
    0
```

will compile, so saying that. you need to indent div [] like so

```
view : Model -> Html -> Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ h2 [] [ text ("Counter: " ++ (toString model)) ]
        , button [ type_ "button", onClick Add ] [ text "add" ]
        , button [ type_ "button", onClick Sub ] [ text "subtract" ]
        , button [ type_ "button", onClick Reset ] [ text "reset" ]
        ]
```

also, the type annotation for view is off, currently you have

```
view : Model -> Html -> Msg
```

but it should be

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
```

Just a tip for when you are learning, you can leave off the type alias

```
--view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
```

is perfectly fine, you can add the annotations later when you are more comfortable with the language, that's how I learned.

See [here](https://ellie-app.com/pFkqq3vQVa1/1) for a link to the working version.

Comment: Sorry I made a typo in my original snippet. I'm new to elm so I didn't notice the spacing. Above is how my code that was producing errors looked.

Answer (score 0):

Your type definition is a little bit wrong. The following:

```
view : Model -> Html -> Msg
```

Should be:

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
```

`Html Msg` is a single type. The corresponding type definition is `type alias Html msg`. `msg` starts with a lower case which indicates that this type is a generic type. This means that any type could be placed here. We could, for example, write `Html Int` or `Html String`. Since the view code returns messages when we click a button for example, we use this message type as the generic type. This results in `Html Msg`.